# MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm new in mongo and i try do make a connection but i receive an error that i don't kwon how to solve, the error is the below:

```
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string. did not connect
(node:21807) [MONGOOSE] DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: the `strictQuery` option will be switched back to `false` by default in Mongoose 7. Use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);` if you want to prepare for this change. Or use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);` to suppress this warning.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

my code is the follow:

index.js

```
    /* MONGOOSE SETUP */
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6001;
    mongoose
      .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
      })
      .then(() => {
        app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Port: ${PORT}`));
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

.env file

```
MONGO_URL= 'mongodb+srv://User:Password@cluster0.is8ykod.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
PORT = 3001
```

I think that MONGO_URL is not see like a string but i don't understand why, I have already try to use :

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

but in receive this error :

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/Users/gianlca/Desktop/progetto/server/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

i can't rename it like '.cjs' cause the import that i have in the file they start to not work too

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL)`?

Comment: It print undefined

Comment: Where is your `.env` file?

Comment: in the same directory

Answer (score 1):

Your .env file is outside the root directory. If you put it inside the main project folder, it works fine.

Just tested and confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure You have specified Database Name on the URI.

The URI Should be:

```
mongodb+srv://User:Password@cluster0.is8ykod.mongodb.net/yourDataBaseName?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: it's not for this, i have write the same link that i have take from mongodb

Comment: You have to replace the user, password and database name to your details on MongoDB Atlas. Then Only the link will work.

Answer (score 0):

In package.json file:

If you have a line that says `"type": "module"` change it to `"type": "commonjs"`

If you don't have the line:  Add `"type:": "commonjs"` like shown in the picture

[image]

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question I can't use commojs because I have some import a the top of index.js if i change "type": "module" in "type": "commonjs" the import does not work anymore

Comment: It's great that you want to help, but in general, pasting screenshots of code is not encouraged. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557.